# File-Upload Standard LWC Component not working in Community

Tags: lightning-web-components, community, digital-experience

I have placed a File-Upload component, on my LWC, onto a Community page.  I keep getting a Javascript error when I try and test it in preview mode. The error is "l.createComponent is not a function".  I have selected the "Allow site guest users to upload files" in settings and have also tested the LWC on a Lightning Record Page and it works, so this is a Community problem.

Any ideas on why this is not working?

Thanks

[image]

Comment: Can you please [edit] the question to add a skeleton of your LWC code with specific code snippets showing where `l.createComponent` is used or where you use the file upload component otherwise? As it stands there likely isn't enough information to let someone answer you.

Comment: @PhilW l.createComponent is part of the LWC runtime, so not something the developer can, or should, call directly. I do agree that code is necessary to resolve this, though.

Comment: So, it's just the standard file-upload LWC.  There is not JS.  

<lightning-file-upload
                label="test"
                name="Tester">
</lightning-file-upload>

Comment: @sfdcfox I suspected, hence the "or where you use the file upload component otherwise"...

Comment: @aksnys please [edit] the question to add more detail, including code snippets for any of your code that appears in the error stack trace (and the stack trace itself, perhaps). Showing the template for your LWC would be helpful too.

Comment: It would also be good to know what template your digital experience is based on. Again, add to the question via [edit], don't add comments.

Comment: I added the error.  My LWC is literally just the File-Upload component now... So, no JS, etc. (It works on the Lightning Record Page but not the Community still)

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you are using a LWR (Lightning Web Runtime) Template for your community.

If so, the lightning-file-upload component is not currently (as of Winter 22 release) supported.

See LWR documentation's considerations here:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.232.0.exp_cloud_lwr.meta/exp_cloud_lwr/get_started_comp_limitations.htm